# Lamport timestamps with variable message travel time

Tags: algorithm, timestamp, distributed-computing, logical-operators, clock

I think I'm misunderstanding something with [Lamport timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_timestamps). It appears that it expects that messages take the same time to travel between distributed endpoints.

Lets say that process `p1` sends messages `m1` and `m2` sequentially to process `p2`. Following the pseudocode in the Algorithm section of the article, we have:

```
# we start at 0
time(p1) = 0

# we send m1
time(p1) = time(p1) + 1 = 1
send(m1, 1)

# we send m2
time(p1) = time(p1) + 1 = 2
send(m2, 2)
```

If `m1` reaches `p2` before `m2` everything is fine. But if `m2` comes first, we get:

```
# we start at 0
time(p2) = 0

# we receive m2 first
time(p2) = max(2, time(p2)) + 1 = max(2, 0) + 1 = 3

# we receive m1 second
time(p2) = max(1, time(p2)) + 1 = max(1, 3) + 1 = 4
```

So in `p2`'s local time (`time(p2)`) `m2` has time of 3, and `m1` has time of 4. That is the opposite of the order in which the messages were originally sent.

---

Am I missing something fundamental or do Lamport timestamps require consistent travel times to work?

Answer (score 0):

The time of a message is the time contained in the message, not the time of the process receiving the message.

The timer is logically shared between the two processes, so it needs to count events (sends) by both processes, which is why the receiver adds one to the time when it receives a mesage.

The algorithm attempts to maintain the two processes' timers in sync, even if messages are lost or delayed, which is why the receiver takes the maximum of its view of the time and the sender's view of the time found in the message. If these are not the same, some message has been lost or delayed. That will result in the two processes having different views of the time, but the clocks will be resynchronised when the next message is sent and received (in either direction).

If the two processes simultaneously send a message, the two messages will contain the same time, which is why it is not a total order. But the clocks will still eventually be resynchronised.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Are you saying that it was never the point that the timestamps of receiving messages in p2 should be ordered in the same way (< or >) as the timestamps of sending the messages in p1? If yes, then what is the point/use for the logical clock anyway?

Comment: @hmm The timestamps in the message are never rewritten; they are as they were when the message was sent. So, no, it was not the intention to produce "receive timestamps". However, note that a reply to a message -- or another action triggered by a message, as in the motivating example in the first paragraph of the linked article -- will necessarily have a greater timestamp than the message it is responding to, which allows some degree of ordering of network events.

Comment: As is pointed out in the WP article, this is a stepping stone towards the idea of vector clocks. It's useful to understand the applications and shortcomings of this algorithm in order to appreciate the value of network clocks. I recommend reading Lamport's papers; although academic, they are generally quite readable.

Comment: Quote from the second paragraph: "Process B receives the message, and as a result sends its own read request message to the disk. If there is a timing delay causing the disk to receive both messages at the same time, it can determine which message happened-before the other: ( {\displaystyle A} A happens-before {\displaystyle B} B if one can get from {\displaystyle A} A to {\displaystyle B} B by a sequence of moves of two types: moving forward while remaining in the same process, and following a message from its sending to its reception.)"

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it should guarantee order of events if you can reach them with with these two transitions. And in our case we can. `sm1` is before `sm2` in `p1` (because we sent them sequentially). `rm1` and `rm2` in `p2` are after `sm1` and `sm2` in `p1` respectively, because sending messages is before receiving. So we have (1) `sm1 -> rm1`, (2) `sm2 -> rm2`, (3) `sm1 -> sm2`. And by transitivity... fuck, there is nothing to give us `rm1 -> rm2`. Ok, I think I get it now. If you confirm that my understanding is correct, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @hmm receiving a message is not an event in this model, so there is no rm1 and rm2 to compare. The receiver can compare the messages by looking at their timestamps; the timestamp is transmitted with the message, which is how the second type of move works. B knows the correct order of two messages sent by A, and in some cases she can also deduce the order of messages sent by C, if C is known to be responding to a message sent by A.